# Understanding Delegates Generics

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I am going through a course on developing extensible software on pluralsight and in one of the slides, this code comes up. My understanding of delegate so far has been that it is used to point to other methods but i cannot figure out what's the purpose of delegate here and if anyone can point me in the right direction please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written there, it isn't very useful... They could have used [`Action<OrderItemProcessedEventArgs>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and it would have been equivalent. (`Action<>` is the generic delegate for methods that don't return anything. Its official description is something like *Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value.*)

The delegate as written (and the `Action<OrderItemProcessedEventArgs>`) represent a method that returns `void` (so that doesn't return anything) and that accepts a single `OrderItemProcessedEventArgs` argument. So for example:

```
public void MyMethod(OrderItemProcessedEventArgs arg)
{
}
```

would be a method compatible with that delegate.

Now... that big block of code creates a `CommerceEvents`, that seems to be a container of events (not C#-`event`s, directly delegates), that some pieces of code can "subscribe" by assigning methods to the properties (`OrderItemProcessed` in this case). Some other code, when necessary, will call `OrderItemProcessed(someOtherItemProcessedEventArgs)`, passing a "descriptor" of why the "event" was executed (the `OrderItemProcessedEventArgs` class)

Comment: ok. the delegates i know they are used like this CommerceModuleDelegate = pointtoamethod and then CommereceModuleDelegate("Passsomevalue"). However in this case, it's passing a class as a parameter but where will it get executed?

Comment: @user1490835 Read the added part

Comment: @user1490835 They are implementing the [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern, with what is called in the wiki *maintains a list of its dependents, called observers* being the `OrderItemProcessed` property.

Answer (score -2):

The delegate you have declared, represents any method which takes a generic T argument and returns void. T can be any class. You can also look into Func and Action delegates which are also generic in nature.